# iOS app thru AIR SDK rejected due to System Configuration Reachability API

Tags: flash, air, app-store

I developed my app for iOS using Adobe Flash CC with AIR SDK 18.0 running on Windows 7. My app does not require nor communicate with the internet/network data to work.

Unfortunately, my binary is rejected by Apple due to:
"During review, we found that your **app does not load its contents and stays blank when the device is connected to a cellular network or Wi-Fi network.**

Please review the Reachability iPhone program code sample that demonstrates the use of the **System Configuration Reachability API to detect the absence of Wi-Fi and Wireless Wide Area Network** (WWAN) services. Your app can then take appropriate action at the first point where network services are required."

Apple took a screenshot of my app, which showed a black screen.

I have tested the app on personal iPhone 5 (on airplane mode and with wifi/data turned on) without issues; at this point, I'm not sure what's causing the error or how to go about fixing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I want to clarify that my app (android version) works fine on google play store (exact same programming code compile in Adobe Flash Pro CC with android AIR SDK). It's just that when I generate app for iOS that's it's rejected by Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

Do as they say. Test against connectivity and act upon it. You could e.g. try to establish a connection to the internet via NetConnection and show a message when that returns false. You could also try to find a matching ANE out there that provides a function to call, to check of the device currently has Connectivity. Take a look at the [CoreMobile ANE](http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/) by Milkman Games. Moneyquote:

> Network Connection Monitoring. With CoreMobile, you can determine if the internet connection is available using a single function call- or if you need real time updates, listen for the connection being lost or gained with one simple event. Like all CoreMobile's features, networking monitoring works seamlessly across iOS and Android.

Just make sure to not show nothing on a missing Internet-Connection, and instead show that there is a problem with connectivity, so that the Appstore-Dwarfs will be satisfied.

Comment: I want to clarify that my app (android version) works fine on google play store (exact same programming code compile in Adobe Flash Pro CC with android AIR SDK). It's just that when I generate app for iOS that's it's rejected by Appstore

Comment: So I assume your app is structured like crooksy88 mentioned in the other answere and you load some kind of content onInit from a remote location? If so, it would be best to debug those requests. The long way would be that you make sure that your API is accessable all the time with minimum downtime and a good connection to the general net (test it with a CDN if you can). Can you give more Informations on what your App is loading?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is crashing on launch.

Apple mentioning the network connection might be a red herring. They could have seen the blank screen and just assumed your app was trying to load content.

Something might be going wrong when you publish your app for the App Store rather than publishing for Ad Hoc or debugging profiles.

Do you change anything prior to publishing for the App Store?

Comment: I want to clarify that my app (android version) works fine on google play store (exact same programming code compile in Adobe Flash Pro CC with android AIR SDK). It's just that when I generate app for iOS that's it's rejected by Appstore

Comment: Yes. It's being rejected because it's crashing on launch. So you need to figure out what in your startup code is causing the crash.